# How can a macro search for another cell which have the same value, and then change the value's?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, lookup

I want the macro to look for same value as in `B2`. And then copy the value from range `D2:G2` to the found range. In this example `D9:G9`.

Thank you in advance :D.

I tried:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim myRng1, myRng2 As Range, cell As Range

Set myRng1 = Range("A4:A1000")
Set myRng2 = Range("D2:G2")

myRng2.Select
Selection.Copy

For Each cell In myRng1
    If Range("A2") = Range("A" & cell.Row) Then Range("D" & cell.Row).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Find()
Dim Findcode As String
Dim Rng As Range

Range("A2:F2").Select
Selection.Copy
Findcode = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").Value
If Trim(Findcode) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:A60000")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=Findcode, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems great. I think though that instead of `.Range("A4:A60000")` it should be column B